# I am in the middle of transfering my website to a new server and new domain and getting error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, machinekey

I am in the middle of transferring my website to a new server and new domain. Everything works except when I log into the website (using the asp.net membership feature) i get redirected back to the old url and get this error:

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

?Why is it redirecting to the old url

Comment: Did you search your code to see if you missed a reference to the old URL?

Comment: Thank you RadioActiveEd, yes it was in my sitemap and site.master page. tHANKS AGAIN!!